# Unnecessary Error when assigning amount of Listeners of an Event to variable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, error-handling, variable-assignment

I have a `class` **EventClass** with a `static event`:

```
public class EventClass : Monobehaviour {
        public static event Action OnEvent1; 
        }
```

And I also have a `class` **Class2** where I need the **amount** of **listeners** of `OnEvent1`:

```
public class Class2 : Monobehaviour {
        private readonly int? amountOfListeners = EventClass.OnEvent1.GetInvocationList().Length; 
        } //The error occurs for ".OnEvent1."
```

I don't see why that would be bad practice, but **vs** gives me an **error** `(cs0070)` that an `event` *can't be assigned*.

Normally that makes sense but in this case I am not assigning the event but rather the **amount of listeners**, so there shouldn't be that error right?

---

I could make an additional method in `EventClass` that returns the amount of listeners but if there are multiple events it would get a bit messy.

Also I can't imagine that there's no way to simply assign it to a variable...Am I missing something?

---

Using visual studio **c#** with Unity

Comment: At least you'd get a NullReferenceException when you use OnEvent before the first client connected

Comment: @PMF The same error occurs when doing a null check before assignment

Comment: That's probably the problem. You can't assign (or copy) the event instance. But both having a static event as well as needing to know the invocation list from outside(!) appears strange to me. Can you explain why you think this is a good design and what you intend to do?

Comment: The Event has a bunch of async listeners. When calling them I want to display the progress with a progress bar. For that I have a script attached to the progress bar that moves it by 1/amountOfListeners every time an async listener finished its method. So in the ProgressBar script I need the amount of listeners to calculate the amount of movement for the progressbar...

Comment: @PMF And as only the Progressbar script needs this amount I think it would be confusing if I create a method for it in the Events script

Comment: I see... What about handling the progress bar state in the class that owns the event? There you also know when the event is invoked and when it's done. That gives you the ability to ensure you get the 0% and 100% case right.

Comment: "I think it would be confusing if I create a method for it in the Events script". I don't think so. Accessing internals of a class from outside is even worse.